# crystal report negative and positive value designing

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to display negative values as

```
(-)0.257
```

and posive numbers as

```
(+)0.367
```

I have tried to create a formula as

```
if({CashSalesdtls.cround}<0) then
'(-)'+totext(abs({CashSalesdtls.cround}))
else
'(+)'+totext(abs({CashSalesdtls.cround}))
```

But totext() is rounding my values to two decimal places, I need three decimal places.
Please help me with any other option to achieve the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention number of decimals in `ToText` function.

```
if({CashSalesdtls.cround}<0) then
'(-)'+totext(abs({CashSalesdtls.cround}),3)
else
'(+)'+totext(abs({CashSalesdtls.cround}),3)
```

For these type of cases you need to first refer documentation which will provide you explanation with examples. link below

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic629.html